# UIImageView frame is right, contentMode is right, image not displayed correctly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimageview

I pick an image from photos:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let imageCropper = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageCropperVC") as! ImageCropperViewController
    imageCropper.delegate = self
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    present(imageCropper, animated: false, completion: {
        imageCropper.imageView.image = image
    })
}
```

Then crop this image:

```
@IBAction func crop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let croppedCGImage = imageView.image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: cropArea)
    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)
    delegate.processCroppedImage(image: croppedImage, cropper: self)
}
```

Then pass the data a collection view cell:

```
func processCroppedImage(image: UIImage, cropper: ImageCropperViewController) {
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
    let i = Side(context: managedObjectContext)
    i.image = imageData
    imagePickerTarget!.knowledgeComponent = i
    cropper.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When the cell gets the data, it does this:

```
if let imageData = knowledgeComponent?.image {
        if let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data) {
            buttonStack.isHidden = true
            imageView.isHidden = false
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
```

But the image isn't displayed correctly, it's zoomed in.

I checked the values,

- the frame of all views are correct (300 * 400),
- the size of the image is roughly the same (301* 401),
- the scale and inset of the image is correct

I've look every question I can find but all of them don't solve my problem, I suspect there's something wrong with my image data, could it be the case? If not, what could be?

This bug makes me not want to use `UIImageView` anymore :(

Comment: Did you try displaying the image before cropping it? Maybe there's an issue with the `imageCropper`? Try bypassing the cropper and displaying the result, this way can start debugging properly and catch where the problem is happening.

Comment: @TawaNicolas I just tried that, this time it works fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem (sort of), thanks to @TawaNicolas's hint, there's something wrong with the image cropper, even though the image size is right, maybe on the iPad an image sized 300*400 doesn't equal to an imageView with a size 300*400?

Anyway, it seems like I'm able to change the outcome by tuning the image cropper, hooray!